# Testing AWS API Gateway with cURL

Tags: linux, curl, aws-api-gateway

I do have a simple AWS API Gateway implementation protected by an AWS_IAM Authorization.

I just want to test from command line via cURL :

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://<API_ID>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage?type=type&category=category&lc=lc&passprhase=passprhase&product=product'
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<AWS_ACCESS_KEY>/20200127/eu-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"","variables":{}}'
```

but keep getting the follow error :

```
Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.
```

Can someone advice what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 17):

AWS V4 signature authentication is supported in `curl` starting from version 7.75, so you should be able to call your AWS resource this way:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://$API-ID.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage?type=type&category=category&lc=lc&passprhase=passprhase&product=product' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--user $ACCESS_KEY:$SECRET_KEY \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz" \
--data-raw '{"query":"","variables":{}}'
```

Note that you may need to add in the `--aws-sigv4` value your region and service.
For example: `--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:eu-west-2:execute-api"`

You can find more documentation here: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_AWS_SIGV4.html

And the documentation for the CLI option here: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--aws-sigv4

Comment: Wow - I am at AWS since 10 years and never figured it out.  That's the coolest tip I saw this year.  Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I could suggest to use `awscurl` which is much easier.

To install `awscurl` click [here](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl). For documentation you can refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html).

Example to call apigateway to call lambda for POST query is below.

> awscurl --service execute-api -X POST -d '{ "alias" : "xyx", "type" : "LDAP" }' https://.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/user/groups/get --region us-west-2  --access_key ACCESS_KEY --secret_key mfBl0YJRsXDue4C5F5B6rz1eUpQpA8uC24RtSnsg --security_token SECURITY_TOKEN

Comment: Or to list the details about an s3 bucket, from the install page,                                                       awscurl --service s3 'https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com' | tidy -xml -iq

Answer (score 5):

AWS_IAM authorization uses [Sigv4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) and its calculation process requires values certain headers - Date being one of them. You are passing x-amz-date as a part of the "SignedHeaders" field, but not actually passing it with the other headers.

One way to create the right curl command to invoke an API with AWS_IAM would be to use [Postman application](https://www.getpostman.com/). Add in the API URL and select "AWS Signature" under Authorization tab. You can then select the "Code" option and get the full curl command which would look something like this -

```
curl -X POST \
  https://$API-ID.execute-api.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/$STAGE/$RESOURCE \
  -H 'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=$ACCESS_KEY/20200128/$AWS_REGION/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=$SIGNATURE_VALUE' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'host: API-ID.execute-api.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com' \
  -H 'postman-token: 15f9498e-95b7-f22b-eed9-016cdea07424' \
  -H 'x-amz-date: $DATE_STAMP'
```

[Create a Canonical Request for Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html)

Comment: Thanks fore replying, Suraj! 
I have actually copy/pasted the command from Postman (cURL) after having provided the AWS Signature creds .. but it still doesnt work. Would it be possible for you to show/send the steps and commands needed to perform the call ?

Comment: @user161183 Does this new curl command have the date header? Have you tried hitting the same URL from Postman?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html