# API Gateway 403 with IAM authorization enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway, aws-signature

I've created an API on API Gateway and without authentication I'm able to access the API without any issues.

I then enabled IAM authentication and now I get 403 on Postman and this message:

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

On Postman I'm sending the authorization as `AWS Signature` and still get the same error.

On AWS I'm have full access to API Gateway since I have AdminFullAccess permissions.

I don't get any headers on the response that could help me debug the issue as mentioned here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When using AWS Signature, did you populated `AccessKey` , `SecretKey` and potentially `SessionToken` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Everything is populated

Comment: Are you sure the Path is valid? You deployed the API from API Gateway Console?

Comment: what about the region and service in postman for AWS Signature?

Comment: The path is valid. If I remove the authentication it works fine. Yes deployed via the console. Yes it's filled as well. Region `eu-west-2` and service `execute-api`.

Comment: try using curl: `curl --request GET "your-endpoint" \
--user $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
--aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:region:service"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932855/testing-aws-api-gateway-with-curl

Answer (score 0):

The request doesn't work on Postman because I have multiple profiles.

I got this working via `awscurl` and by specifying the profile.